# How do I fix math operation type errors with Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've ben experimenting with Swift UI and I keep running into issues with simple math operations like divide or negate throwing type errors. It seems to come up more when I start using a function that uses CGFloat. I tried doing specific casting, but that doesn't seem to help, I just get the message "Ambiguous reference to member '-'" and I don't understand where the ambiguity is coming from.

This is the SwiftUI code I'm trying to use:

```swift
   var body: some View {
        let baseHeight:CGFloat = 300.0

        let transparentColor:Color = Color.white.opacity(Double(0.0))

        return ScrollView(.vertical){
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading) {
                    MapView()
                    .frame(height: baseHeight)
                    .offset(y: 0)

                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        HStack {
                            CircleView<TitleView>(fillColor: transparentColor, scale: baseHeight / min(CGFloat(1) + CGFloat(geometry.frame(in: .global).minY), baseHeight)) {
                                TitleView(city: self.selectedCity)
                            }
                            .frame(minWidth: CGFloat(0), maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: baseHeight, maxHeight: baseHeight)
                            .offset(y: -baseHeight) // Here I get the error "Ambiguous reference to member '-'"
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }

                Spacer().padding(.bottom, baseHeight / 3.0)

                    ForEach(cities) { city in
                        Text(city.name)
                            .padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                $selectedCity = city
                        }
                    }

                    Spacer()
                }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: error message]

How can I a) fix this, b) prevent it from happening again, c) understand why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: With SwiftUI the errors might not actually be where Xcode tells you they are...Best is to comment out line by line until you get to the real issue. Could you provide a more complete example code?

Comment: The first thing to do is try compiling with [Xcode 11.4, currently in beta](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). The Swift compiler team has dramatically improved [the compiler's diagnostic framework](https://swift.org/blog/new-diagnostic-arch-overview/), so you're likely to get a much more helpful error message.

Comment: Cannot reproduce... Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: Just an hax-solution is to say `baseHeight*-1`

Comment: @Vollan "Ambiguous reference to member '*'" :P

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the onTapGesture line, that was invalid apparently, and made the math error show up. I replaced it with a button to handle the click instead. Really misleading errors, but hopefully that’s fixed with newer versions of Xcode.